# Prolog - Recursively accessing list's list element and getting the total sum

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a query `average(X, A)` that returns true if X exists in a prolog database and if A is the average price of the items within a store

Sample output

```
?- average(best_smoothies,A).
A = 2.66667
No
```

Prolog Database

```
store(best_smoothies, [alan,john,mary],
      [ smoothie(berry, [orange, blueberry, strawberry], 2),
        smoothie(tropical, [orange, banana, mango, guava], 3),
        smoothie(blue, [banana, blueberry], 3) ]).

store(all_smoothies, [keith,mary],
      [ smoothie(pinacolada, [orange, pineapple, coconut], 2),
        smoothie(green, [orange, banana, kiwi], 5),
        smoothie(purple, [orange, blueberry, strawberry], 2),
        smoothie(smooth, [orange, banana, mango],1) ]).

store(smoothies_galore, [heath,john,michelle],
      [ smoothie(combo1, [strawberry, orange, banana], 2),
        smoothie(combo2, [banana, orange], 5),
        smoothie(combo3, [orange, peach, banana], 2),
        smoothie(combo4, [guava, mango, papaya, orange],1),
        smoothie(combo5, [grapefruit, banana, pear],1) ]).
```

My attempt:

```
numSmoothie([_|T],X) :- numSmoothie(T,A), X is A+1.
numSmoothie([], 0).

priceSmoothie([_|T],X) :- priceSmoothie(T,A), X is A+1.
priceSmoothie([], 0).

average(X, A) :-    store(X,_,S),
                    numSmoothie(S, SmoothieCount),
                    writeln("Number of smoothies is: "),
                    writeln(SmoothieCount),
                    store(_,_,[smoothie(_,_,C)]),
                    priceSmoothie(C, SmoothiePrice),
                    writeln("Total price of smoothies is: "),
                    writeln(SmoothiePrice),
                    A is SmoothiePrice / SmoothieCount.
```

I'm able to get the number of items on the list by simply counting per S. However, I can't seem to be able to access the list's list elements (aka the price) and be able to sum it up as a whole.

Output that I'm getting

```
?- average(smoothies_galore, A).
Number of smoothies is:
5
false.
```

Based on the output, it's clear that I'm not accessing the store price element. Why is `store(_,_,[smoothie(_,_,C)])` not valid to be able to access the item prices?

Would appreciate any help on this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on the output, it's clear that I'm not accessing the store
>   price element. Why is `store(_,_,[smoothie(_,_,C)])` not valid to be
>   able to access the item prices?

This will only unify with a store with only one smoothie.

i.e if you add:

`store(single_smothie_shop, [p1,p2,p3],
      [ smoothie(berry, [orange, blueberry, strawberry], 2)]).` to your KB then query:

`?-store(What,_,[smoothie(_,_,C)]).
C = 2,
What = single_smothie_shop.`

Which is the only result of that query.

One way you can get what you want is with the query:

`?-store(Store,_,Smothies), aggregate(r(count,sum(Price)),S^N^member(smoothie(S,N,Price),Smothies),r(Count,TotalPrice)), Average is TotalPrice/Count.`

Comment: Hmm I see, so essentially I'm only able to access stores with just one smoothie. Anything with more than one, and it returns false.

Comment: Got to implement the said query, appreciate the help! So essentially I had to ditch my current method of thinking since it would only allow me to work on one at a time! This function allows me to count them all!